# Using free() on static array of char*

Tags: c, static, malloc, free

I have the following code:

```
void fn(char *string , int flag)
{
    static char* array_of_strings[100];
    static int index = 0;

    if(flag)
    {
        array_of_strings[index] = (char *)malloc(10);
        strcpy(array_of_strings[index] , string);
        index++;
    }
    else
    {
        //How should I deallocate the memory here?
        index--;
    }
}
```

What will happen to the array_of_strings[index] if the else block is met? Will it be automatically dealocated or will it stay after fn() returns? Should I be using this line in place of the comment:

```
array_of_strings[index] = 0;
```

Or can I use free() like this:

```
free(array_of_strings[index]);
```

Will this free the block of memory allocated by malloc?

Comment: As usual, every `malloc` (or `realloc`, etc.) should have a corresponding `free`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all OK:

```
/* Allocate an array to hold 100 char * pointers: OK */
static char* array_of_strings[100];

/* Allocate space to hold one 9-character string: OK */
array_of_strings[index] = malloc(10);

/* Free string: OK */
free(array_of_strings[index]);
```

This will cause you grief:

```
/* Whoops: step on the pointer, then try to free it.  Not good :( */
array_of_strings[index] = 0;
free(array_of_strings[index]);
```

> Q: What will happen to the array_of_strings[index] if the else block
>   is met? Will it be automatically dealocated or will it stay after fn()
>   returns?

A: If you malloc something, it will remain allocated until you "free()" it ... or until the program terminates.

Comment: Q: Does this help?  Any questions?

Answer (score 3):

A call

```
free(array_of_strings[index]);
```

does not deallocate a static array of `char*`, it deallocates a block of memory reserved for 10 `char`s that has been allocated dynamically, and a pointer to which has been stored in a `static` array of pointers. This is the right thing to do to avoid memory leaks.

This line, on the other hand, makes it impossible to access a dynamically allocated block of memory:

```
array_of_strings[index] = 0;
```

This situation is commonly known as a "memory leak". You should avoid it.

Note that it is not uncommon to set the `free`d pointer to zero to avoid dereferencing it accidentally, like this:

```
free(array_of_strings[index]);
array_of_strings[index] = 0; // Prevent a "dangling reference"
```

If you do it this way, you can tell that a pointer at `array_of_strings[index]` is no longer valid at some later time.